# data of form field suddenly transferred to another field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

When I fill one field, the letters are transferred to another, can be transferred at all in a text block of another component. Before that everything worked fine, just a moment something went wrong, do not understand that. Please help.[gif with problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngZDA.gif)

my component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import {Row, Col, FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl, HelpBlock} from 'react-bootstrap'
import SelectizeSimple from '../../SelectizeSimple'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'

import {
  setUserSecureId,
  setUserName,
  setCompany,
  setAddressFirstLine,
  setAddressSecondLine,
  setCity,
  setState,
  setZip,
  setVat,
  setEmail
} from 'store/user'



class PersonalInfo extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputName:''
    }
  }

  submitFormPersonalInfo = (event) => {
    axios.post('', {
      query: 'mutation UpdateUser($form:UpdateUserInput!) { update_user (input:$form) { id } }',
      variables: {form: this.props.updateUser},
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }

  changeUserName = (event) => {
    this.props.actions.setUserName(event.target.value)
  }

  changeCompany = (event) => {
    this.props.actions.setCompany(event.target.value)
  }

  changeAddressFirstLine = (event) => {
    this.props.actions.setAddressFirstLine(event.target.value)
  }

  changeAddressSecondLine = (event) => {
    this.props.actions.setAddressSecondLine(event.target.value)
  }

  changeCity = (event) => {
    this.props.actions.setCity(event.target.value)
  }

  changeState = (event) => {
    this.props.actions.setState(event.target.value)
  }

  changeZIP = (event) => {
    this.props.actions.setZip(event.target.value)
  }

  changeVat = (event) => {
    this.props.actions.setVat(event.target.value)
  }

  changeEmail = (event) => {
    this.props.actions.setEmail(event.target.value)
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="tab-wrap-inner-header">
          <div className="title_primary title_primary__inner">Personal Info</div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-wrap form-wrap__large-right-gap">
          <form action="" className="form-default">
            <FormGroup className="form-group__indent-bot-big">
              <ControlLabel>
                E-mail
              </ControlLabel>
              <div className="form-edit-box">
                <FormControl placeholder="email@gmail.com"
                             onChange={this.changeEmail}
                              value={this.props.updateUser.email}/>
                <button className="btn-edit btn-edit__left-gap">
                  Edit
                </button>
              </div>
              <HelpBlock>This address will appear on your License.</HelpBlock>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="form-group__indent-bot-big">
              <ControlLabel>
                Password
              </ControlLabel>
              <div className="form-edit-box">
                <FormControl type="password" placeholder="*********"></FormControl>
                <button className="btn-edit btn-edit__left-gap">
                  Edit
                </button>
              </div>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="form-group__indent-bot-big">
              <ControlLabel>
                Name
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                onChange={this.changeUserName}
                value={this.props.updateUser.name}/>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="form-group__indent-bot-big">
              <ControlLabel>
                Company Name (optional)
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                onChange={this.changeCompany}
                value={this.props.updateUser.company}
              />
              <HelpBlock className="flexbox align-center">
                <div className="radio-box radio-box__square radio-box__nogap">
                  <FormControl type="checkbox" id="radioGroup11"></FormControl>
                  <ControlLabel htmlFor="radioGroup11" className="radio-box__pseudo-radio"></ControlLabel>
                </div>
                <label htmlFor="radioGroup11" className="label-default">Hide information about my country from my profile</label>
              </HelpBlock>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="form-group__indent-bot-big">
              <ControlLabel>
                Adress Line 1
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                onChange={this.changeAddressFirstLine}
                value={this.props.updateUser.address_first_line}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="form-group__indent-bot-big">
              <ControlLabel>
                Adress Line 2 (optional)
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                onChange={this.changeAddressSecondLine}
                value={this.props.updateUser.address_second_line}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="form-group__indent-bot-big">
              <ControlLabel>
                City
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                onChange={this.changeCity}
                value={this.props.updateUser.city}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="form-group__indent-bot-big">
              <ControlLabel>
                State / Province / Region
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                onChange={this.changeState}
                value={this.props.updateUser.state}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="form-group__indent-bot-big">
              <ControlLabel>
                ZIP / Postal Code
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                onChange={this.changeZIP}
                value={this.props.updateUser.zip}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="form-group__indent-bot-big">
              <ControlLabel>
                VAT number (if applicable)
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                onChange={this.changeVat}
                value={this.props.updateUser.vat}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-primary__submit" onClick={this.submitFormPersonalInfo}>
              Save Changes
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return ({
    updateUser: state.user.updateUser,
  })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators({
    setUserSecureId,
    setUserName,
    setCompany,
    setAddressFirstLine,
    setAddressSecondLine,
    setCity,
    setState,
    setZip,
    setVat,
    setEmail
  }, dispatch),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PersonalInfo)
```

my reducer:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
export const GET_USER_INFO = 'GET_USER_INFO'
export const GET_CURRENT_USER = 'GET_CURRENT_USER'
export const SET_USER_AVATAR = 'SET_USER_AVATAR'
export const SET_USER_BANNER = 'SET_USER_BANNER'
export const SET_USER_SECURE_ID = 'SET_USER_SECURE_ID'
export const SET_USER_NAME = 'SET_USER_NAME'
export const SET_COMPANY = 'SET_COMPANY'
export const SET_ADDRESS_FIRST_LINE = 'SET_COMPANY'
export const SET_ADDRESS_SECOND_LINE = 'SET_COMPANY'
export const SET_CITY = 'SET_CITY'
export const SET_STATE = 'SET_STATE'
export const SET_ZIP = 'SET_ZIP'
export const SET_VAT = 'SET_VAT'
export const SET_BIOGRAPHY = 'SET_VAT'
export const ADD_TRACK_TO_FAVORITES = 'ADD_TRACK_TO_FAVORITES'
export const SET_SOCIAL_LINKS = 'SET_SOCIAL_LINKS'
export const SET_EMAIL = 'SET_EMAIL'

const initialState = {
  userInfo: {},
  currentUser: {},
  updateUser: {
    id: '',
    name: "",
    avatar: "",
    address_first_line: "",
    address_second_line: "",
    city: "",
    state: "",
    zip: "",
    vat: "",
    company: "",
    biography: "",
    secure_id: "",
  },
  favorite_tracks:[],
  social_links:[]
}


export const getUserInfo = (user) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    var state = getState();
    return axios.post(API_URL, {
      query: "query User($id:ID) {user(id:$id) { id name email avatar social_links { type url } banner email biography address_first_line address_second_line city state zip vat company secure_id created_at is_current tracks { id name logo created_at composer publisher } favorite_tracks { id name logo created_at is_favorite user { id name } } followers { id name tracks_count } followings { id name tracks_count }}}",
      variables: {id: user}
    }).then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_USER_INFO,
        data: res.data.data.user
      })
    })
  }

export const getCurrentUser = () =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    var state = getState();
    return axios.post(API_URL, {
      query: "{ current_user () { id name email biography created_at is_current } }"
    }).then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_CURRENT_USER,
        data: res.data.data.current_user
      })
    })
  }

export const AddTrackToFavorites = (id) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    var state = getState();
    return axios.post(API_URL, {
      query: "mutation AddTrackToFavorites($input:AddTrackToFavoritesInput!) { add_track_to_favorites (input:$input) { id } }",
      variables: { input: { id: id } }
    }).then(res => {

    })
  }

export const RemoveTrackFromFavorites = (id) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    var state = getState();
    return axios.post(API_URL, {
      query: "mutation RemoveTrackFromFavorites($input:RemoveTrackFromFavoritesInput!) {remove_track_from_favorites (input:$input) { id }}",
      variables: { input: { id: id } }
    }).then(res => {

    })
  }

export const setUserAvatar = (avatar) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_USER_AVATAR,
      data: avatar
    })
  }

export const setUserBanner = (banner) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_USER_BANNER,
      data: banner
    })
  }

export const setUserName = (name) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_USER_NAME,
      data: name
    })
  }

export const setCompany = (company) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_COMPANY,
      data: company
    })
  }

export const setAddressFirstLine = (address) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_ADDRESS_FIRST_LINE,
      data: address
    })
  }

export const setAddressSecondLine = (address) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_ADDRESS_SECOND_LINE,
      data: address
    })
  }

export const setCity = (city) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_CITY,
      data: city
    })
  }

export const setState = (state) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_STATE,
      data: state
    })
  }

export const setEmail = (state) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_EMAIL,
      data: state
    })
  }

export const setZip = (zip) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_ZIP,
      data: zip
    })
  }

export const setVat = (vat) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_VAT,
      data: vat
    })
  }

export const setBiography = (biography) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_BIOGRAPHY,
      data: biography
    })
  }

export const setSocialLinks = (links) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_SOCIAL_LINKS,
      data: links
    })
  }

export const setUserSecureId = (value) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_USER_SECURE_ID,
      data: value,
    })
  }


const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [GET_USER_INFO]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      userInfo: {
        ...state.userInfo,
        created_at: action.data.created_at,
        is_current: action.data.is_current,
        tracks: action.data.tracks,
        followers: action.data.followers,
        followings: action.data.followings,
        favorite_tracks: action.data.favorite_tracks,
      },
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        id: action.data.id,
        email: action.data.email,
        secure_id: action.data.secure_id,
        name: action.data.name,
        avatar: action.data.avatar,
        banner: action.data.banner,
        company: action.data.company,
        address_first_line: action.data.address_first_line,
        address_second_line: action.data.address_second_line,
        city: action.data.city,
        state: action.data.state,
        zip: action.data.zip,
        vat: action.data.vat,
        biography: action.data.biography,
        social_links: action.data.social_links
      },
      favorite_tracks: action.data.favorite_tracks,
      social_links: action.data.social_links
    })
  },
  [GET_CURRENT_USER]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      currentUser: action.data
    })
  },
  [SET_USER_AVATAR]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        avatar: action.data
      }
    })
  },
  [SET_USER_BANNER]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        banner: action.data
      }
    })
  },
  [SET_USER_NAME]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        name: action.data
      }
    })
  },
  [SET_COMPANY]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        company: action.data
      }
    })
  },
  [SET_ADDRESS_FIRST_LINE]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        address_first_line: action.data
      }
    })
  },
  [SET_ADDRESS_SECOND_LINE]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        address_second_line: action.data
      }
    })
  },
  [SET_CITY]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        city: action.data
      }
    })
  },
  [SET_STATE]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        state: action.data
      }
    })
  },
  [SET_ZIP]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        zip: action.data
      }
    })
  },
  [SET_VAT]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        vat: action.data
      }
    })
  },
  [SET_BIOGRAPHY]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        biography: action.data
      }
    })
  },
  [SET_USER_SECURE_ID]: (state, action) => {

    return ({
      ...state,
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        secure_id: action.data
      }
    })
  },
  [SET_EMAIL]: (state, action) => {

    return ({
      ...state,
      updateUser: {
        ...state.updateUser,
        email: action.data
      }
    })
  },
  [ADD_TRACK_TO_FAVORITES]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      favorite_tracks: action.data
    })
  },
  [SET_SOCIAL_LINKS]: (state, action) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      social_links: action.data
    })
  },
}


export default function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type]
  return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
}
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why the form elements go through the global redux state instead of the internal component state and go together to the global redux state after clicking the form submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because same constants for multiple redux action ids:

```js
export const SET_COMPANY = 'SET_COMPANY'
export const SET_ADDRESS_FIRST_LINE = 'SET_COMPANY'
export const SET_ADDRESS_SECOND_LINE = 'SET_COMPANY'
```

need replace with:

```js
export const SET_COMPANY = 'SET_COMPANY'
export const SET_ADDRESS_FIRST_LINE = 'SET_ADDRESS_FIRST_LINE'
export const SET_ADDRESS_SECOND_LINE = 'SET_ADDRESS_SECOND_LINE'
```